# How complex can a Differential Equation be?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, education

When I was first being introduced to differential equations, my teacher began by asking the other student and me to write down the **most complex differential equation we could think of** and gave us 10 or 20 seconds to do so, before judging what we'd written and choosing a winner. The purpose of this was mainly to check we knew was a differential equation *was* and to make us think about what they might look like.

My question is, what is the most complex differential equation that could reasonably be written down in 10 seconds? The only restriction is that it must be a DE - use your imagination!

This requires some kind of definition of the word 'complex' in this setting. To illustrate what I mean, I will provide two examples which I would consider to be no more complex than each other.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\sin(x+y)\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(5\log x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)=\exp(-\sin(7x^3\sqrt y)
\end{align}$$

These are both second order and can be written as $y''+f(x)y'=g(x, y)$. So I suppose what I am looking for is the most complicated **form** of differential equation that you can come up with.

**EDIT:**

Don't let my example mislead you into thinking there are restrictions. I would recommend involving complex numbers, integrals, vectors, perhaps matrices, perhaps something like $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^{\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: $\varphi (f^{(n)}, \ldots , f', f) = g(\underline{x}) $

Comment: Only two variables? Only real-valued functions?

Comment: $y'^9+\cos(y')=x^y$ or $\log_y\lfloor y'\rfloor=\log_{y'}\lfloor y\rfloor$.

Comment: I think the underbar on @Andy's answer is implying that it's a vector. It can be any number of variables. In general a 'differential equation' can be any sufficiently smooth function of any order of derivatives of some function and its partial derivatives along its variables.

Comment: Going to complex variables doesn't fundamentally give you anything new because any differential equation in complex variables can be re-expressed as a set of real valued differential equations, although sometimes it's useful to express things in terms of complex variables because that tells you more about the solutions of the differential equation. So your example of taking the derivative to itself as a power is in principle fine.

Comment: @Exomnium I know, I think he edited it. I am very much aware of what differential equations are now, although if that is a technical definition it is a useful comment. What is meant exactly by 'sufficiently smooth'?

Comment: It's a vagary to cover myself. Mathematicians would usually start by studying differential equations where the defining function is completely smooth, but in applications this is often insufficient and you'd like to be able to talk about non-smooth solutions as well (such as solutions containing kinks), so a notion of 'weak solutions' was developed. And in general depending on the situation you could have very singular source terms. For instance you can have Poisson's equation whose source was shaped like a measure 0 fractal (like the Cantor set or Sierpinski's gasket), and it works.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes solutions don't exist (even in the extremely nice case of smooth coefficient functions and iirc a linear differential equation), which isn't necessarily that bad, after all systems of real polynomials don't necessarily have solutions, so it's just something you have to worry about, but not very much in applications.

Comment: As @avid19's answer alluded to a more difficult question arises when you want to include more elements. There are a lot of generalizations of the notion of differential equation, including stochastic diff eqs. A more 'mundane' but probably no less important generalization is what are called '[delay differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation)' where the derivative can depend on the function at a past time (or in other words the equation is 'non-local'.) This is essentially what happens when you want to allow derivatives of arbitrarily high order.

Comment: One criteria that's kind of important is whether or not the differential equation admits an initial value problem. The non-local differential equation that the Fabius function obeys ($f'(x) = 2 f(2x)$) doesn't for instance (basically because it depends on itself 'in the future' in an essential way). You can see this because the Fabius function and $f(x)=0$ are both solutions of that equation, but they have the same derivatives at 0 to all orders.

Comment: @Exomnium Perhaps you could transfer these valid points to an answer, also providing what you consider the most complex DE?

Comment: But asking for the most complex DE is like asking for the most complex polynomial. You can make it arbitrarily complex.

Comment: @Exomnium In which case I'd like to see how you might write this arbitrary complexity in a succinct way.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that a teacher posing the  irksome and pointless test described in this question involving (a) an undefined notion of complexity for differential equations and (b) a time trial for writing them down had a class with just two students?

Comment: @Rob I suppose not - he was the dad of the other student and we were both learning two years ahead of everyone else, and he was a very effective teacher.

Comment: Good for the three of you! Out of context it just sounds dreary.

Answer (score 2):

I guess a pretty general ("complex") form is:

$$\dot{y}=Ay$$

With $y(0)=y_0$

Where $A$ is some usually, but not necessarily, linear operator.

This is known as an abstract Cauchy problem. If $A$ is linear, and some fancier words like self adjoint and bounded, then:

$$y(t)=e^{At}y_0$$

This is a pretty general form, and leads to what's called $c_0$ semi group theory.

More complicated differential equations might be something I study, SPDEs. Take your favorite ODE or PDE and add a term $\dot{W}$. $W$ is some noise term called Brownian motion and $\dot{W}$ is the derivative of Brownian motion. However Brownian motion is not differentiable. How's that for complicated? :)

Examples:

$$\partial_t u=\partial_{xx} u +u\dot{W} \text{ (Stochastic Linear Heat)}$$

$$\partial_t u=\partial_{xx} u +(\partial_x u)^2-\infty+\dot{W} \text{ (KPZ)}$$

Note that these are special cases of a Cauchy problem. The first one being linear, the second one not.

Comment: What does the $-\infty$ mean? Is it some kind of notation for a regularization scheme?

Comment: @Exomnium Correct. There's a divergence coming from the product.

Answer (score 1):

As requested here is a very succinct way of writing a very broad class of non-local differential equations
$$f\left(\underline{x},\left\langle \delta_j(\underline{x},\varphi_{k}(\underline{x})),\varphi_{i}(\underline{x})\right\rangle \right)=0$$ where $\underline{x}$ varies over some arbitrary manifold $M$ (if you wanted to go really crazy I guess it could be an arbitrary diffeology, but I don't think anybody uses those), $\varphi_i(\underline{x})$ are a family of real valued functions (technically they could take on values in an arbitrary manifold, but I didn't want to figure out how the next part generalizes. Although it's not 100% necessary because you can talk about coordinate patches), and $\delta_j(\underline{x},\varphi_k(\underline{x}))$ is an arbitrary family of distributions on $M$ parameterized by $\underline{x}$ and all of the $\varphi_i(\underline{x})$, and $f$ is some arbitrary function of all of those (assuming nothing about its smoothness, and guaranteeing nothing about the existence of solutions).

Although as written this is actually so general that it includes not only all local and non-local differential equations (including fractional derivative differential equations, which can be thought of as delay differential equations), but pretty much any equation between functions, including integral equations (which covers weak solutions of PDEs), polynomials, functional equations, recursion relations on sequences, etc. I don't know if it covers stochastic differential equations (outside of the linear case, I think I remember seeing that linear SDEs can be converted to certain PDEs). It also doesn't cover stuff like 'p-adic differential equations' which use an entirely different field than $\mathbb{R}$. But ultimately you can push to more and more general formalizations but you lose any kind of ability to prove general statements.